# There is no table accessible from sqlline.bat in ApacheIgnite

Tags: ignite

I have this code and I expected that when I run !table command in sqlline.bat I will see table called **Person**, but there is no table.

What I have to do to see the table there?
Am I expecting correctly, that there should be created table automatically for each cache?

Thank you

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var cfg = new IgniteConfiguration
        {
            BinaryConfiguration = new BinaryConfiguration(typeof(Person),
                typeof(PersonFilter))
            
        };
        IIgnite ignite = Ignition.Start(cfg);
        
        ICache<int, Person> cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<int, Person>("persons");
        cache[1] = new Person { Name = "John Doe", Age = 27 };
        cache[2] = new Person { Name = "Jane Moe", Age = 43 };

        var scanQuery = new ScanQuery<int, Person>(new PersonFilter());
        IQueryCursor<ICacheEntry<int, Person>> queryCursor = cache.Query(scanQuery);

        foreach (ICacheEntry<int, Person> cacheEntry in queryCursor)
            Console.WriteLine(cacheEntry);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
class Person
{
    [QuerySqlField]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [QuerySqlField]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Person [Name={Name}, Age={Age}]";
    }
}

class PersonFilter : ICacheEntryFilter<int, Person>
{
    public bool Invoke(ICacheEntry<int, Person> entry)
    {
        return entry.Value.Age > 30;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL table shouldn't be created automatically for the cache. To add SQL table, you should define the schema: https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/schema-and-indexes

It can be done using annotations, QueryEntiny configuration, or by creating the cache using DDL(CREATE TABLE command).